# Can no longer create and edit service hooks

Tags: azure-devops

I'm configuring several projects in an Azure DevOps environment, and set up several Service Hooks to link the various projects to a Trello board. I was able to add hooks and test them, but suddenly and for no apparent reason I can no longer see my hooks or edit them. Instead, I get an error that says "You do not have sufficient permissions to view or configure subscriptions."

I am an Organization and Project administrator for each of these cases.

Comment: Would you mind listing everything you've tried? And all the permissions you have set? It's too broad of a question, it's gonna get closed if it's not edited with more information.

Comment: Hi, how's the things going? Does the permission `Edit project-level information` set `Allow` is work for you? if it is not work for you and still facing any issue, feel free to leave comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have been the Org and project admin.

Please go **Project setting** -> **Permission** -> search and enter your account permission page. Ensure the permission of **Edit project-level information** is **Allow**. Also, ensure this corresponding permission of groups you are keeping in does not be denied.

[image]

You can see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-permissions):

[image]

You can see, the operation of View and Set subscription is associate with this permission setting. Please ensure yourself account and the group are all **Allow** this permission.

Comment: @DanielLakin Awesome！ You could [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/541930).